# What can I do if my USB flash drive / SD-card is write-protected or read-only?

Tags: usb-drive, sd-card, readonly

When I plug in my USB flash drive (or SD card), it shows up on my computer as *write-protected* or *read-only*. I am unable to transfer data to it, nor can I modify or delete any files already stored on it. I also cannot repartition or reformat the drive using GParted or other tools, including Windows Disk Management, DiskPart. The drive does not have a write-protect switch.

Why did this happen and what can I do about it? Is there a way to remove the write protection?

> *This question comes up often and the answers are usually the same. This post is meant to provide a definitive, [canonical answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4383/faq-on-usb-flash-memories-that-become-read-only-and-my-proposed-solution/4388#4388) for this problem.*
> Feel free to edit the answer to add additional details.
>
> This question was copied from [this](https://superuser.com/q/1125282/131062) superuser.com question by [bwDraco](https://superuser.com/users/73918/bwdraco), and then edited.
>
> <sub>*(To moderators)* This question is thus intended to be a master dupe target. (Jargon of stackexchange.com, meaning to mark other similar questions as a duplicate of this.)</sub>

**Answer**
<sub>(TL;DR: Sorry for giving the answer here; a moderator deleted [my anwser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350682/190880). I've fixed it following his/her request, but probably it's been missed.)</sub>

See the [original question and answer](https://superuser.com/q/1125282/131062) in superuser.com.  In short, probably all you can do is retrieve the data and throw away the device.